# Iframe Not Showing Up on Page

Tags: html

how come my iframe isn't showing up at: 
http://orcaaccounting.com/helloFriend.html

Here is my code,

```
<p style="text-align:centre;"> 
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riFyKUyGb4k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>
```

Thanks, I am sure I am missing something small but this is my bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the `allow` attribute which contains `encrypted-media` and the `embed` portion of the url. This one should work. You should copy the Embed link from the YouTube video itself, that is the appropriate way to get the iframe.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/riFyKUyGb4k" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

The src is wrong add embed instead of watch.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/riFyKUyGb4k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: yus! it worked! thank you!
If I wanted to embed a video file that is on the same server as the webpage how would I do that? Just put the file name in quotations in src?